# Retry java RestTemplate HTTP request if host offline

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

Hi I'm using the spring `RestTemplate` for calling a REST API. The API can be very slow or even offline. My application is building the cache by sending thousands of requests one after the other. The responses can be very slow too, because they contains a lot of data.

I have already increased the Timeout to 120 seconds. My problem now it that the API can be offline and I get a `org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool` exception.

In the case when the API ist offline, the application should wait and try again until the API is online again.

Can I achieve this in `RestTemplate` out of the box without building exception-loops on my own?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot, you have to manually do it. Also, if 120 seconds time is not sufficient to get data, then you must contact the API developer.

Answer (score 34):

I had same situation and done some googling found the solution. Giving answer in hope it help someone else. You can set max try and time interval for each try.

```
@Bean
  public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

    int maxAttempt = Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxAttempt"));
    int retryTimeInterval = Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("retryTimeInterval"));

    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempt);

    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(retryTimeInterval); // 1.5 seconds

    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
    template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    return template;
  }
```

And my rest service that i want to execute is below.

```
retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
        System.out.println("inside retry method");
        ResponseEntity<?> requestData = RestTemplateProvider.getInstance().postAsNewRequest(bundle, ServiceResponse.class, serivceURL,
                CommonUtils.getHeader("APP_Name"));

        _LOGGER.info("Response ..."+ requestData);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong");
        });
```

Comment: Which library is it?

Comment: It is spring lib. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry

Comment: If you are working with Spring-boot you can just include the starter `spring-boot-starter-batch` to get that dependency with the version aligned to the spring-boot version.

Answer (score 29):

You can also tackle this annotation-driven using Spring Retry. This way you will avoid to implement the template.

Add it to your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Enable it for your application/configuration

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class MyApplication {
  //...
}
```

Guard methods that are in danger of failure with `@Retryable`

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Retryable(maxAttempts=5, value = RuntimeException.class, 
             backoff = @Backoff(delay = 15000, multiplier = 2))
  public List<String> doDangerousOperationWithExternalResource() {
     // ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use Spring Retry project (https://dzone.com/articles/spring-retry-ways-integrate, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry).

It is designed to solve problems like yours.

Answer (score 0):

This approach saved my day.!!!Resilience saved my day.[Resilience retry][1]

````
       RetryConfig config = RetryConfig.custom()
                .maxAttempts(4)
                .waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
                .failAfterMaxAttempts(true)
                .build();
        RetryRegistry registry = RetryRegistry.of(config);


        HttpEntity<String> request =
                new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        Retry retry = registry.retry("notification-endpoint-"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        AtomicReference<Integer> retries = new AtomicReference<>(0);
        retry.getEventPublisher().onRetry(e -> {
            log.info("Retrying here!!!. Count: {}", retries.updateAndGet(v -> v + 1));
        }).onError(e->{
            log.error("Failed to get to client.");
        });
        if(requestPojo.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
             response = Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(
                    retry,
                    () -> restTemplateConfig.restTemplate()
                            .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class)).unchecked().get();
        }
        else if(requestPojo.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
            response = Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(
                    retry,
                    () -> restTemplateConfig.restTemplate()
                            .exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class)).unchecked().get();
        }```


  [1]: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry
````

Comment: Please add your import-statements and groupid/artifactid libraries.