# How implement a retry mechanism for restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've implemented a java method which call to external services via a Resttemplate. As well,  i've implemented some additional business logic   also inside that method. How can i implement a retry mechanism for these rest calls. Need to consider below points as well.

1. I cannot add a retry for entire method.
2. It's better to add retry for rest calls(via resttemplate).
3. There should be a way disable retry options for unwanted rest calls.

Comment: I think you can do something like this. Make a loop from 0 to 9 and make a call. If you get success then break a loop and go ahead with result else iterate through it. If it is not returning somthing in 10 calls then why should you call that method and waste your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retry java RestTemplate HTTP request if host offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352484/retry-java-resttemplate-http-request-if-host-offline)

Comment: Its not like a good approach. i've already implemented these methods. I need to do this by minimizing the modifications for current implementations. If we add this retry for resttemplate using common configuration, then i maybe not need modify the current implementation

Answer (score 12):

Spring provides a retry mechanism with **@Retry** annotations. You have to use the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring provides the following annotations.

Spring retry annotations

**@EnableRetry** – to enable spring retry in spring boot project

**@Retryable** – to indicate any method to be a candidate of retry

**@Recover** – to specify fallback method

I provide below the sample code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
}
```

You can refer the complete example to know more about it.

- [Spring retry module](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-retry-module/)
- [Spring retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)
- [spring retry way to handle failures](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-retry-way-to-handle-failures)

Comment: This annotation should be added to the method level. For my scenario, i cannot do that.If we got an error from one rest call,  then entire method will be executed again.

Comment: If you want, you can split the methods into small cohesive functions/methods and then you can add the annotations.

Comment: There are few limitations for this annotation. Specially, it can't be added to same class methods and private methods as well.

Comment: Yes, there are some limitations, but it  abstracts away lot of things and make it easier to implement.

Comment: If you are working with Spring-boot you can just include the starter `spring-boot-starter-batch` to get that dependency with the version aligned to the spring-boot version.

Answer (score 11):

You may add retry mechanism inside `HttpClient` and use it for `RestTemplate`, somethng like this:

```
@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientFactory() {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()            
        .setRetryHandler((exception, executionCount, context) -> {
            if (executionCount > 3) {
                log.warn("Maximum retries {} reached", 3);
                return false;
            }
            if (<some condition for retry>) {
                log.warn("Retry {}", executionCount);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })
        .build();

    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
}
@Bean
public RestTemplate customRestTemplate(@Qualifier("clientFactory") ClientHttpRequestFactory clientFactory){ 
    return new RestTemplate(clientFactory);
}
```

Comment: Just note that this solution only works for low level network failures. It does not retry on http status != 2xx, like for example a 502.

Comment: @AnnevanderBom Did you find a solution that works with custom HTTP statuses?

Answer (score 0):

for rest api call you can implement the retry mechanism on the client level where actual rest call going

```
 @Retryable(value = Exception.class, maxAttemptsExpression = "${retry.maxAttempts}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${retry.maxDelay}"))
    public Optional<T> getApiCall(String url, String token, Class<T> resClass) {
        ResponseEntity<T> response = null;
        try {
            logger.info(url);
            // create headers
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            // set `accept` header
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.setBearerAuth(token);
            // set custom header
            // headers.set("x-request-src", "desktop");
            // build the request
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("", headers);
            // use exchange method for HTTP call
            try {
                response = this.restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, resClass, 1);
            } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
                return errorService.throwException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, EKDError.LIFPRO406);
            }
            if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                return Optional.ofNullable(response.getBody());
            } else {
                return errorService.throwException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, EKDError.LIFPRO406);
            }
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
            logger.error("Exception in api call : ", e);
            return errorService.throwException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, EKDError.LIFPRO407);
        }
    }
```

now  max attempts and delay is configurable set application.properties maxAttemptsExpression = "${retry.maxAttempts}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${retry.maxDelay}"